# CSS left column and header fixed and centered

Tags: css

I have an issue related to be able to keep header and left column fixed and centered. The header css for such task works fine but I'm not able to get left column fixed and centered. If i set the position property to fixed, it automatically keeps on the left and is not centered.

I have a sample code of my work here http://jsfiddle.net/hvN7Q/3/

As you can see in the sample, if you resize the window, left column keeps on the left and it's not centered.

Anyone could help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -whatever` where whatever is half the width of your left column. This will keep it in the center.

Comment: in which div should i place such properties?

Comment: whatever you want to be horizontally centered.

Comment: I have place such properties within .left_column DIV and well, it center just at the middle of the screen but thanks, you gave the idea of how to do it.... many thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Hi Watson, finally it works fine, only that I noticed one issue related to when I resize the browser width less than the width of the document. The left column disappear while header and and body keeps left aligned. It's possible to solve this?

Comment: hmm, I don't see why it would disappear. If you post what you've done on a fiddle again, I could check it out.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution with respect the below query. The link is: http://jsfiddle.net/hvN7Q/4/

Hope, this help!